# Computing the fractional laplacian of a logarithm function

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fractional-calculus

Are there explicit formulas to compute the fractional laplacian $(-\Delta)^{s/2}\log  |x|$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $s\in (0,2)$?

Comment: Yes, I think there is an  article   "Fractional Laplace operator and its properties" by Mateusz Kwaśnicki page 168 (2019) where you can find your answer.

Comment: @GabS thank you very much for the reference!